# Property [myTruck] does not exist on this collection instance having 'myTruck' as method in the model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel eloquent relationship and was trying to retrieve joined records from 2 tables namely; trucks and tbl_drivers. A trucks assigned is to be assigned to a single driver. I want to fetch the recrod of the truck assigned to a particular driver after following the documentation and other source i came up with it but  and it gives me the error '**Property [truck] does not exist on this collection instance**', i tried searching through different result of people that encounter such problem and i couldnt see similar problem or coundnt comprehend theirs. 
Below is my Model Class

```
   <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Drivers extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'driver_id_no','driver_name','driver_phone', 'driver_address',
    ];
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'tbl_drivers';
    //primary key
    public $primaryKey ='driver_id';

    public function myTruck()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Truck', 'driver_id', 'driver_id_no');
    }
}
```

Below is my Controller method that i expect to fetch the driver details with the truck details

```
 public function show(Drivers $driver)
    {
        //
        $truck = Drivers::find($driver)->myTruck;            
        return view('drivers.show',compact('driver','truck'));
    }
```

If i make changes like
`$truck = Drivers::find(1)->myTruck; //where 1 is an ID of an existing record`
And i tried outputting  {{$driver}} , it gives me the driver's information but {{truck}} does give me nothing on the view ie show.blade.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below solves my problem
// defining the relationship in the model

```
public function myTruck()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Truck', 'driver_id_no', 'driver_id_no');//        
    }
```

Tn the above code; the first driver_id_no is a foreign key or coulmn from the Trucks table while the second is a column precisely the primary key of the Driver table in which the model is defined.
The code below is from my Controller Class in the method i need to fetch the truck assigned to a driver.

```
$driverTruck = Drivers::find(1)->myTruck;
```

In the above; i asumed 1 in the find() is a primary key with value 1 in the driver table.      In the view, I fetch the columns using

```
 {{$driverTruck ->truck_model}}//where truck_model is an attribute/Column of trucks table
```

To explain how the code works, After defining the relationship. I fetch the row in the truck table with column driver_id_no which a primary key of the driver table. This automatically fetch the truck asigned to a driver

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull a field from a collection of objects, rather than a method / relationship from an object.  The complementary problem is the you may be pulling an injected `Driver` object from route-model binding using the parameter `$driver`.  This is pushing an object into the `find()` route, which expects an integer.

Start simple and then add the complexities.  So try just pulling in the `id`:

```
 public function show($driver_id)
```

Then, get your single truck object:

```
 $driver= Drivers::find($driver_id);
```

Or, to save a DB call, load the `myTruck` relationship eagerly:

```
 $driver= Drivers::with('myTruck')->find($driver_id);
```

You should now be able to access the relationship on the single `$truck` object:

```
$truck = $driver->myTruck;
$truck->whatever_field_on_the_truck
```

I've changed the variable name from `driver` to `truck` to help explain it maybe a little better.  This is way more verbose than needed, but you can trim it after it gets working.  Assuming the `myTruck` relationship is correctly formed, this should work for you.

Comment: ` $driver= Drivers::with('myTruck')->find($driver);
        $truck = $driver->myTruck;
        return dd($truck); `   Still gives me same error    I tried    $driverall = Drivers::where('driver_id_no','$driver')->firstOrFail()->myTruck; 
        //$driverall = Drivers::find(1)->myTruck;

Comment: The code was able to fetch the record i want but on passing the value of the argument in the method; it gives me 
404
Not Found
for string of driver_id_no